# In eclipse quick fix customization possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, customization

while creating a JFrame derivative in eclipse, the quick fix given by eclipse is "import unimported files" and when I do the fix, it imports

```
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

and I have to import every file when I declare other components, Is it possible to change the quick fix option in eclipse, so that I could change it to

`import javax.swing.*;`

thanks for your works below in advance

Comment: Just type `Jbut<Ctrl space>` and it will auto-complete to JButton *and* add the import of JButton for you. Or type Ctrl-Shift-O to auto-import all the missing classes. Using wildcard imports is bad practice. You should avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose the menu item: Window->Preferences.
2. Select Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports
3. You can then select the number of items that are imported before Eclipse chooses to use a wildcard for that package. The default is 99.